# Who should I consider when thinking about "peer recommendations"?

Tags: hiring-process, references, recommendation-letter

Who do hiring managers expect to see as "peer recommendations"?

Some I have considered are:

- former colleagues;
- other users on the StackExchange network (field-appropriate), or just my reputation itself?
- local user groups (especially in technical fields, such as local Linux or Java User Groups)

In your experience as a candidate or hiring manager, how are peer recommendations considered? Other there others I should consider?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to The Workplace! Right now your questions are rather broad -- do you have a specific question about how best to go about *obtaining* peer recommendations, or how they might be used in the hiring process?  Or, are you being asked for peer recommendations and don't know how to ask?

Comment: @jcmeloni sorry, you are right. I have modified my question. It should be more specific now.

Comment: Thanks; I've made some more edits to make it better fit the SE model and also be as widely-applicable as possible.  I hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best recommendations are from former colleagues who now work for the company you want a job with.  If I am hiring you, I care most about whether you are going to be a productive and positive influence on my group.  If a former colleague recommends you, then it means that someone thinks you were a productive and positive influence on their group.  If that person now works for my company, then it's not just some stranger saying so but someone who is staking their reputation to a certain extent on your performance.  Such recommendations can often skirt some or even most of the hiring process.

Second best is recommendations from other former colleagues.  These mean much the same, but of course there's no risk for the person making the recommendation, and I probably don't know them from Adam.  But it means someone out there thought you were worth working for.  (Unless it's someone notable.)

Recommendations from Stack Overflow, users groups, etc. don't mean much at all.  You haven't worked with these people in a business environment, so the fact that they like you doesn't mean much.  (And in the case of Stack Overflow, it'd be superfluous, as I can see everything you've done anyway.)

Comment: Looks like the best way to get peer recommendation is just working hard and collaborate with colleagues.

Comment: I wil add to be careful to select only people who are respected to give references. The worst refernce you can have is from a person who works at the company you want to get hired by that they think is an idiot.